# Sending a push notification from node.js via Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, push-notification

I've been reading a lot about Azure Push Notification Hub but there's one thing I don't seem to be able to find a definitive answer for. I want to modify an existing node.js service which runs on my own server so it can send push notifications through Azure's Push Notification Hub. I don't want to host any code or data on Azure, I just want it to look after Push Notifications. I've read that this is possible via a rest api on Azure but I don't seem to be able to find any info on that rest api such that I can access it from an external node service. I don't want to host my node service in an Azure mobile service.

Does anyone know if this is possible or can anyone point me on at any docs or samples?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Azure Notification Hub SDK for node.js. You don't need to host the node.js application on Azure: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-nodejs-how-to-use-notification-hubs/

Comment: Thank you. I had tried azure.createNotificationHubService as described on that page but failed to make. After your reply I tried again and with the correct hub name and it did allow me to send via gcm in that I received no errors. I can't see any evidence at the portal that my push made it to azure. What I don't understand is why I have to choose a send notification service like gcm or apns. I thought one of the advantages of using Push Notification Hub in was that I do not need to know the type of device I am sending to. I thought I just send to Azure and it routes to the correct device.

Comment: The azure portal has now updated to show 1 API call. It still shows zero pushes but that's probably because no device has registered yet for the notifications. I'll look at that now.

Comment: I see now that I need to use notificationHubService.send with a template to allow me to send to any device type. Thanks to your help, I might now be making some progress.