# Error while sending web-push notifications from node API deployed on Azure Server

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, web-push

I have created an API that will subscribe for notification and notify all the subscribed clients with a notification. It worked locally fine, but once I deployed it to Azure it is not able to push the notifications to Clients. Is there something I am missing which must be blocking the outward notification from the server? Any help is appreciated.

Note: The NodeAPI is working perfectly fine, and I get proper responses, just notifications are not being sent or must be blocking.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port =8080;

const webpush = require("web-push");
const publicKey = ""; \\blacked out for security purpose
const privateKey = ""; \\blacked out for security purpose
webpush.setVapidDetails("mailto:example@yourdomain.org",publicKey,privateKey);

const notificationClient = [];

app.use(express.json());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
app.listen(port,()=> console.log("listening to port:"+ port));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.status(200).send("API is Running");
});

app.get('/api/notify',(req,res)=>{
    const payload = {
        notification:{
          title: "Message From Heaven ",
          icon: '/assets/icons/icon-128x128.png',
          body: 'We beleive in you.\n Do your deeds good ',
          data:{ url:"https://google.co.in"},
          vibrate: [500,110,500,110,450,110,200,110,170,40,450,110,200,110,170,40,500]
        }
      };
      notificationClient.forEach(clientSub => {
          console.log(clientSub);
        webpush.sendNotification(clientSub, JSON.stringify(payload));      
      });
    res.status(200).send("Success: ClientsNotified: "+ notificationClient.length);
});

app.post('/api/subscribeNotification',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req);
    // const  {id} = req.params;
    // const  {Sub} = req.body;
    const clientSub = req.body;
    notificationClient.push(clientSub);
    res.status(200).send("Notification Subscribed");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ [sabbour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47582/sabbour) for your answer

Instead of ***NodeJS*** push notification via azure you can use the `Azure Notification Hub SDK` for NodeJS.

Refer here for implement the Push notification in NodeJS application [notification-hubs-nodejs-push-notification-tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-nodejs-push-notification-tutorial)

Refer for more info [here 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24606723/15997690) and  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30073969/15997690)